# VueJs + Vite router pages don't open

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, vite

I created a vue app with the cli command `vue init vue@latest` which uses `Vite`. I'm trying to make an app that has 3 (at the moment) pages. Home page, create entry form page and a browse entries page. I've been trawling google, youtube and stackoverflow to find solutions, but nothing seems to work so far.

This is my `router/index.js` file:

```js
import {createRouter, createWebHistory} from 'vue-router';
import {HomeView} from '../views/HomeView.vue';

const router = createRouter ({
  history: createWebHistory(import.meta.env.BASE_URL),
  routes: [{
    path: '/',
    name: 'home',
    component: HomeView
  },{
    path: '/create',
    name: 'create',
    component: () => import('../pages/create/CreateEntry.vue')
  }]}); //there's another that is identical but replace 'create' with 'browse'

export default router;
```

`vite.config.js`

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';

export default defineConfig({
  //skipping some stuff
  pages: {
    index: {
      entry: "./src/pages/Home/main.js",
      template: "public/index.html",
      title: "Home",
      filename: "index.html",
      chunks: ['chunk-vendors, 'chunk-common', 'index']
    },{
    create: {
      entry: "./src/pages/create/main.js",
      template: "pages/create/index.html",
      title: "Create",
      filename: "index.html",
      chunks: ['chunk-vendors', 'chunk-common', 'create']
    } //repeats oncce more for browse
  }
});
```

and in my main `src/App.vue` I have the RouterLinks setup like this:

```html
<script setup>
import { RouterLink } from 'vue-router';
</script>

<template>
  <!--omitted -->
  <ul class="menu">
    <RouterLink to="/"<li>Home</li></RouterLink>
    <RouterLink to="/create"<li>Create</li></RouterLink>
    <RouterLink to="/browse"<li>Browse</li></RouterLink>
  </ul>
  <!-- some more stuff -->
</template>
```

```js
//this is the main.js files in each of the respective page folders:
import { createApp } from 'vue';
import CreateEntry from 'CreateEntry.vue';

createApp(CreateEntry).mount(#app);

//and for space's sake, the HTML file is the same as 
//the default that comes when you create your Vue project folder
```

I tried to include `RouterView` elements, but it just caused them to be overlaid onto the main page (not what I want). My pages are setup in a pages// fashion, with each having their respectively named Vue files, an `index.html` and a `main.js` file. The links do not cause errors, no warning pops up in the console, and that's making it very hard to debug the behaviour. Previously I've only used Vue for SPAs, so I'm sure I'm overlooking some step to go to MPAs, I just don't know for the life of me what it is.

this is the file tree, some files omitted for brevity

```
proj
 +--public
 +--src
  |--assets
  |--components
  |--pages
   +--browse
    |--Browse.Vue
    |--index.html
    |--main.js
   +--create
    |--CreateEntry.vue
    |--index.html
    |--main.js
  +--router
   |--index.js
  +--stores
  +--views
  |--App.vue
  |--main.js
 |--index.html
 |--vite.config.js
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a `main.js` for every page you create.

The only important `main.js` in this regard is the one in `src/main.js`

This file is the entry point of your application.

In order to use the router your app has to literally `use()` it.

```
 // src/main.js
 import { createApp } from 'vue';
 import router from 'router/index.js';
 import App from 'App.vue';

 createApp(App).use(router).mount('#app');
```

Furthermore I don't think you need to register the pages in the `vite.config.js`

Comment: I have removed the `main.js` files and the routes setup from `vite.config.js` but it's still giving the same behaviour. the URL will change, but the page will not change to match the respective route, it just stays on the main page, despite the urls being different. No errors.

Comment: Did you add an `<router-view/>` tag into your HTML? E.g.: in App.vue you have somewhere a `<router-view/>` tag, and whenever you go to a different url, the component will render where the <router-view/> is.

Answer (score 0):

In my main `App.vue` file I had a bunch of layout stuff, which seemed to be interfering. I replaced all of that with `<RouterView />` and now it navigates pages and moved it to a pages folder. I guess I misunderstood the docs or something but it works now!

So my `App.vue` looks like:

```
<template>
  <header>
    <!-- same as above -->
  </header>
  <main>
    <RouterView />
  </main>
</template>

<script setup>
import { RouterView, RouterLink } from 'vue-router';
```